# C - How to properly read localized input from stdin?

Tags: c, setlocale

I need to input special characters through stdin and there seems to be a problem doing this. I guess fgetws() doesn't support cp852 (standard console code page of my OS, Win 7 x64 btw). Should I use cp1250 or something else? I tried using chcp 1250 in cmd.exe but that lasts only until I close down the command prompt. I am on Visual C.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main()
{
    wchar_t query[64];
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "croatian");
    wprintf(L"Insert special characters: ");
    fgetws(query, 64, stdin);
    fputws(query, stdout);
    putchar('\n');
    return 0;
}
```

[Console output example](http://i49.tinypic.com/14lr1tv.png)

Comment: So by "special characters" you mean unicode?

Comment: That came out wrong, I meant non-ASCII ones, basically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trying to fix wrong locale settings in your program is the wrong place. You should just set the right locale in your environment and using this value in your code like:

```
setlocale(LC_ALL, "");
```

This is what the man-page tells:

> On startup of the main program, the portable "C" locale is selected  as
>    default.  A program may be made portable to all locales by calling:
>
> setlocale(LC_ALL, "");

EDIT:

Taking a look at your last screenshots to me it seems there's something mixed up while reading input.

**case 1:** (the one without any call to `setlocale`)

... doesn't seem too interesting. As in the (default) "C" locale just contains characters U+00-U+7E even if it *seems* to produce the correct result this is more or less the garbage in - garbage out case.
The value 0x9F is the code page 825 (see: http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Codepage_852) encoding Unicode Character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER C WITH CARON' (U+010D) `č`.

Passing the raw value back and forth there's no big surprise the same output is generated if the same byte is written to terminal again.

**case 2:**

... looks a little bit more interesting.
The value 0x17a is the UTF-16 encoding of the unicode character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH ACUTE' (U+017A) `ź`, which perfectly matches the output shown in your screenshot. As  fputsw seems to corectly map this to the terminal encoding it seems the problem is that the input isn't properly read.

Just to make sure after making changes nothing got confused - you're running the code like this?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>

int main () {
    wchar_t query[64];
    setlocale (LC_ALL, "");

    if (fgetws(query, 64, stdin) == NULL)
      return -1;
    fputws(query, stdout);
    putchar('\n');

    return 0;
}
```

EDIT:

### Locale settings check

I forgot to mention one of the most interesting things about your test: The unicode character 'LATIN SMALL LETTER Z WITH ACUTE' (U+017A) `ź` (the one output in your second screenshot) is exactly represented as the value `0x9f` (that's the one you get reported, when using the "raw" character code) in codepage 1250.

Somehow fgetws seems to interpret character codes using codepage 1250 instead of codepage 825.

As to me it still seems the problem is that the locale settings somehow get mixed up. Probably you should try running the following code and see what locale gets reported.

```
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main (int argc, char *argv[]) {
  char *locale;

  setlocale (LC_ALL, "");
  if ((locale = setlocale (LC_ALL, NULL)) == NULL)
    return -1;

  printf ("%s\n", locale);

  return 0;
}
```

On my system for example this gives output: `es_ES.utf8` The interesting part is the one after the dot '.' as this specifies the character encoding (utf8 in the example given above).

Another thing to check might be the program version of Visual Studio you are using, as there seems to be a bug in older versions setting the default locale. (see: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/709505/setlocale-lc-all-returns-incorrect-default-system-locale)

Comment: What is your locale set to. In case there is such a tool on your os you should be able to see the settings with the `locale` command.

Comment: Under Region and Language -> Administrative it says "Current language for non-Unicode programs - Croatian(Croatia)". Typing chcp in the command prompt says "Active code page - 852". Maybe I need to set it to 1250.

Comment: The rather strange thing is that code page 852 obviously supports the glyphs you're trying to show as pretty well shown by the input line in the linked image. My guess is something gets messed up in the conversion either from codepage 852 to UTF-16 or from UTF-16 back to codepage 852. Probably dumping the read chars as hex might give some insight. AFAIK in windows wchar_t should be encoded in UTF-16. Thus you might check if the conversion from codepage 852 to wchar_t gets properly handled.

Comment: That is a bit out of my league because I've only been learning C for six months or so. But I'll do what I can. Other people have tried it on gcc/MinGW and it works fine. This is how it looks before AND after I use the setlocale function. I used the wprintf's \X format specifier - http://i50.tinypic.com/1zob2ir.png

Comment: I had to `#include <stddef.h>` for gcc to accept `wchar_t`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you mikyra, for trying to help.
Solved by explicitly giving setlocale the default code page of my console as a second argument. Like this:

```
setlocale( LC_ALL, ".852" );
```

Hopefully, no new problems will arise. Thank you, [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x99tb11d%28v=vs.80%29.aspx).

Comment: Users will sure beat you for that - but if it works ... why not.

Comment: This surely turned out to be more interesting than I anticipated. So, should I wait 2 days to accept my own solution or should I accept yours since you thoroughly explained the process of I/O in this case albeit without an actual solution? Btw, why would I check stdin for NULL - for \n input only, maybe?

Comment: Althoug maybe a bit cryptic `if (fgetws(query, 64, stdin) == NULL)` **doesn't** check stdin for NULL **but** the return value of fgetws which will be NULL if some error occured while trying to read. If you only intend to use the program for your own purposes besides esthetics there's nothing wrong with the "solution" of hardcoding character encoding to cp 852. If on the other hand also other users will want to run the program they'll get nothing but garbaged input when using any other charcter encoding than cp 852 so it probably should get fixed to use setlocale in the intended way.

Comment: @mikyra Yes, I'm aware that is not a "real" solution, but this program is not intended to be used by anyone other than myself, so it will do just fine for now. Thank you, once again. Your code gives me "Croatian_Croatia.1250".

Comment: Then as already said the read `0x9f` should represent `ź`. Is it possible that your console settings don't match those of your locale? `chcp` without arguments should show the codepage your console is currently using. This would have to be `1250` if everything is allright. If shows something like 852 then this mismatch would be the correct place to fix. Either by setting your locale to one matching the codepage of the console or by adjusting the cp used by the console to that of your locale. You may check by executing `chcp 1250` prior to starting your program.

Comment: @mikyra There is an obvious mismatch, but to make changes on my console permanent I would have to tamper with the registry. That is something I wish to avoid, if possible. Besides, I am opening a file encoded in cp1250 from which I am collecting data that I am comparing to input encoded in cp852 (my console, naturally) using bsearch after the data has been qsort-ed. It is quite a mess, actually.